# Does anyone have video time algorithm example for XML subtitle that had "start" and "duration" to match video duration?

Tags: javascript, xml, html

Does anyone know how to or had example or a link from someone provided good example?
I had XML file that included "start" time, "dur" time, and subtitle texts.
In HTML5, I have snapshot MJPEG movie. I was able to get the fps duration decimals numbers while the MJPEG video is playing. Now I would like to know how I can use this video duration numbers with subtitle start and duration number so that the subtitle texts can display match as the video running.

Here my XML codes,

```
<transcript>
<text start="2.014" dur="1.276">Greetings fellow nerds.</text>
<text start="3.291" dur="3.446">In this video we&#39;re going to make glow sticks of various colors</text>
<text start="6.738" dur="2.277">and explain a few interesting points about them.</text>
<text start="9.016" dur="2.722">But first I need to crush your expectations.</text>
</transcript>
```

and the Javascript variable name that get the video duration time are profTime.

Here example of HTML video code and the id is profTime,

```
<div class="drsElement" 
 style="left: 47%; top: 52%; height: auto; width: 25%;   text-align:  left; " id="profDiv">
    <div class="drsMoveHandle" style = "position:relative;"><p id="profTime"> Time: 0</p></div>
        <div >
<input type="range" onchange="profOpc()" value="100" id="profOPC" min="20" max="100" />
</div>

    <div style=" width: auto; height: auto; position:relative; margin-bottom:7%;">
        <!-- video images area.... -->
        <img src="prof/0.jpg" style="width: 100%; height:auto;"   class="webcam2"  id="profVid"   alt="Live Stream"  onerror="ErrorPlayProf()"> 

    </div>
            <center>

        <input type="button" onclick="fivesecbackProf()" value="- 5 sec" id ="fivesecbackProfButt" />
        <input type="button" onclick="onesecbackProf()" value="- 1 sec" id ="onesecbackProfButt" />
        <input  type="button" onclick="liveProf()" value="Live" id ="liveProfButt" disabled = "true" />
        <input  type="button" onclick="onesecforProf()" value="+ 1 sec"id ="onesecforProfButt" disabled = "true" />
        <input  type="button" onclick="fivesecforProf()" value="+ 5 sec"id ="fivesecforProfButt" disabled = "true" />
    </center>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You might find this [interactive demonstration of the HTML5 video API](http://www.w3.org/2010/05/video/mediaevents.html) useful.

The algorithm you need isn't particularly difficult. Essentially you want to monitor the progress of the video playback by listening for the progress event and deciding which cuePoint to display based on the video's `currentTime` property. The following is incomplete but should give you the idea.

```
var video = document.getElementById('video');
video.addEventListener('progress', progressHandler);

console.log(document.getElementById('video'));

function progressHandler() {
 //console.log(video.currentTime);
    var currentTime = video.currentTime;
    var cueStart = cuePoint.start;
    var cueEnd = cueStart + cuePoint.duration;

    if (currentTime > cueStart && currentTime < cueEnd) {
       displayCuePoint(cuePoint.text);   
    }
}
```

You would probably make your life a lot easier if you mapped each text node in your XML to a JavaScript object with corresponding properties. Or even better, load the data as JSON in the first instance and save yourself the bother of having to convert it to something more usable.

Comment: So I can replace to profTime instead of currentTime because profTime also get the current time while the video is playing. For cueStart, cuePointstart come from "start" in XML? Same for cuePoint.duration that get from "dur" in XML?

Comment: Yeah if profTime gives you the current time of the video you can use that instead. And yes, cuePoint.start and cuePoint.duration (used to calculate the cueEnd) would come from your XML. You might find it useful to create an array of cuePoint objects from your XML when the data is first loaded.